# Textarea with keyword highlighted: strange cursor behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, summernote

I am using [Summernote](https://summernote.org/) plugin to create a nice textarea and [Mark.js](https://markjs.io/) plugin to highlight a defined keyword (for example `foo`) inside that textarea.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="text"></div>
```

And Javascript code:

```
$('#text').summernote({
   height: 150,
   callbacks: {
       onChange: function (contents, $editable){
         $('.note-editable').unmark({"done": function () {
            $('.note-editable').mark(
                 'foo',
                 {'separateWordSearch': false })
         }})
         }
       }
   }
);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4n9hhc1)

And it's working well. Every time the user writes `foo` in the textarea the word is being highlighted, but I have this issue: when the user writes `foo` the cursor moves to the beginning of the `foo` word and I don't want this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The editable div(s) are not the ideal types to handle inputs. Similar cursor behavior is common where the value of an editable div is being updated explicitly using JS or jQuery. To solve this, you either need to use suitable default input types like `<input>` and `<textarea>` tags.

And that doesn't solve your use case as you wont be able to change the properties of the selected text. So the solution is as follows at client side:

1. Create a global variable to store the updated value of cursor for each such editable div.
2. Update the value of this global variable on each onblur event.
3. Retrieve this global value before highlighting your keyword.
4. Update the cursor to the retrieved value after making the necessary keyword highlights.

Following are the function to retrieve and update the cursor value :

```
function doGetCaretPosition (id, storeTo) {
  var oField = document.getElementById(id);
  // Initialize
  var iCaretPos = -1;

  // IE Support
  if (document.selection) {

    // Set focus on the element
    oField.focus();

    // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
    var oSel = document.selection.createRange();

    // Move selection start to 0 position
    oSel.moveStart('character', -oField.value.length);

    // The caret position is selection length
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }

  // Firefox support
  else if (oField.selectionStart || oField.selectionStart == '0')
    iCaretPos = oField.selectionStart;

  // Return results
  if( window[storeTo] !== undefined || window[storeTo] !== '' )
  {
    //if position is not updated
    if( $(oField).val().length == iCaretPos )
        window[storeTo] = -1;
    else    
    window[storeTo] = iCaretPos; 
    console.log("[doGetCaretPosition Updated]  "+$(oField).attr('id')+" in : "+window[storeTo]);
  }
  else
    console.log("[doGetCaretPosition : failed]");
}


//Set caret position
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', window[caretPos]);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(window[caretPos], window[caretPos]);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
    console.log( "[setCaretPosition Updated]" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Aman, I understand the concept, but I am having difficulty to implement your solution. This is what I have tried https://jsfiddle.net/k4n9hhc1/8/

Comment: The fiddle you provided is throws an error when hiding the element in summernote.js. Please have a look at it.

Comment: There are small changes to the code : 
1. Initialization of global variable with -1
2. while passing the element to the function you need to pass their 0 index.

setCaretPosition($('.note-editable')[0], "global_var");
doGetCaretPosition($('.note-editable')[0], "global_var");

And the fiddle is still throwing errors whenever the keyword highlight happens.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your highlighted text will get a `<markjs highlighted="true">foo</markjs>` tag become.  You have to setup your cursor at the end of that tag. If you have time I will update this post in a hour with the solution.

Comment: Yes, if you have a better code, it would help me a lot